# ubuntu 19.10 no video signal nVidia TI 1050 video card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, 19.10

I have upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 and then 19.10. Since that time I see nothing on both screens except a homogeneous black surface. On the second monitor is blinking the green LED - normally showing with continuous light the supply voltage is on - probably showing the lack of video signal.

Would be possible somehow to repair this ?

If it is impossible have I to delete the whole partition (loosing the earlier settings of ubuntu 18.04) and reinstall the old good ubuntu 18.04?
Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title and the solution within the question. Please user **Your Answer** window below to answer your own question. Then mark your answer as the correct one by placing the green check mark next to it. This will help others.

Answer (score 0):

After starting the computer you can select between the start modes. In the GRUB menu select Advanced options for Ubuntu 19.10. In the next screen select kernel version 4.15.0.70 instead the 5.x series kernel. Use the ↑ and ↓ keys to select which entry is highlighted. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot the selected kernel.